# Unable to upload a private file to s3 bucket/folder with Laravel

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3

I have the following code in my Laravel project:

```
$filename = 'bagel-corp-nda.pdf';

Storage::disk('s3')->put('agreements/'.$filename, file_get_contents($filename),'private');
```

When I fire this code, anyone can go to the link `https://confidential-agreements.s3.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/agreements/bagel-corp-nda.pdf` and see the PDF that was uploaded.   The `'private'` argument isn't making my upload non-public.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure how Laravel handle's private files. I'm wondering how it retrieves them. Could you please upload a temporary random pdf file with "private" option via your form, and reply the address? The one given by you is not working btw

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the visibility is actually private by default according to this [forum thread](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/s3-and-visibility).

> By default, all objects are private: only the owner has full control. When adding a new object, you can grant permissions to individual AWS accounts or predefined Amazon S3 groups.

The quote above is from [Amazon's S3 API Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/archive-RESTObjectPUT.html) which supports that forum thread.

so you should try simply calling it without the third parameter like so:

`Storage::disk('s3')->put('agreements/'.$filename, file_get_contents($filename))`

and make sure that your s3 disk configuration does not have `'visibility' => 'public'`

If it still does not work then you can try following the API documentation and use

```
// Untested
Storage::disk('s3')->put('agreements/'.$filename, file_get_contents($filename), ['x-amz-acl' => 'private'])
```